# __declspec(align) for multiple declarations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, syntax, memory-alignment, declspec

Sorry for the very simple question, couldn't find a googleable answer.

Is this declaration syntax:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float rF[4];
__declspec(align(16)) float gF[4];
__declspec(align(16)) float bF[4];
```

Equivalent to this:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float rF[4], gF[4], bF[4];
```

Or will only the first variable be aligned in the latter syntax?

If it matters, these are local variables inside a global method.

Comment: Where do these declarations appear? Inside a class or struct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan These are local variables inside a global method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  A `__declspec` is part of the storage class and applies to all declarators in the declaration.

Comment: Why do you guys keep deleting and un-deleting your answers :)

Comment: I answered, then David answered with the opposite answer, so I removed mine while I verified that it is indeed correct.  I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Thanks! Have you found this mentioned in the docs anywhere or is this purely from experience?

Comment: [The documentation for `__declspec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx) begins with "the extended attribute syntax for specifying storage-class information uses the `__declspec` keyword..." and storage class is a property of the declaration, not of an individual declarator (just like `static` applies to the whole declaration, not an individual declarator).  My quick test verified that given `__declspec(align(64)) int a, b, c, d, e;`, all five integers are aligned on 64-byte boundaries.

Comment: Thanks again for the comprehensive help.