# Is there a way to use __declspec(align) for for declaring of objects with different type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, declspec

Is there a way to use __declspec(align) for declaring lot of objects in Visual studio? Sth like:

```
__declspec(align)
{
int p1;
long p2
}
```

My question is similar to [__declspec(align) for multiple declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203586/declspecalign-for-multiple-declarations). But this question is for objects with same type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Please write that in the answer section. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't apply a single [`__declspec(align)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx) to a block of unrelated declarations like this. Each individual declarator statement needs its own `__declspec`:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> __declspec( align( # ) ) declarator
> ```

You are probably looking for [`#pragma pack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) instead:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> #pragma pack( [ show ] | [ push | pop ] [, identifier ] , n  )
> ```

For example:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
int p1;
long p2
#pragma pack(pop)
```

```
#pragma pack(push, 16)
float rF[4];
float gF[4];
float bF[4];
#pragma pack(pop)

/*
Alternatively:

#pragma pack(push, 16)
typedef float floatArray4[4];
#pragma pack(pop)

floatArray4 rF;
floatArray4 gF;
floatArray4 bF;
*/
```